# What is the natural length of the spring? - Hooke's Law

Tags: calculus, integration

Question: A spring requires 5 Joules to stretch the spring from 8 cm to 12 cm, and an additional 4 Joules to stretch the spring from 12 cm to 14 cm. What is the natural length of the spring?

I have absolutely no idea how to solve this problem. I know that Work for springs is calculated by $W=\int_a^b F(x) d x$ and I know that Hooke's Law states that $F(x)=k x$. Beyond this knowledge, I cannot figure out how to find the natural length of the spring when given the work required to stretch it two different times.

Please help me... Thank you.

Comment: Hooke's Law defines $x=0$ when the spring is at its "natural length".

Comment: True, I do know that as well. I'm just struggling to figure out how to incorporate that into an equation that will allow me to figure out the natural length.

Comment: A similar question solved here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2115796/find-the-rest-position-of-a-spring-given-its-work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you have a linear spring, since you mention $F(x) = kx$.

Let's also assume that the natural length is not at $x_{o}\neq0$, thus, we can do something like:
$$
F(x) = k(x-x_{o})
$$
Noting that this basically just shift the natural length from zero.

Defining work as $W =\int Fdx$:
$$
W = k\int_{a}^{b}(x-x_{o})dx
$$

At this point the problem just boils down to system of linear equation:
$$
5\text{ joules} = k\int_{8}^{12}(x-x_{o})dx\Rightarrow \frac{5}{k} = (\frac{12^{2}}{2}-12x_{0})-(\frac{8^{2}}{2}-8x_{0})
$$
$$
4\text{ joules} = k\int_{12}^{14}(x-x_{o})dx\Rightarrow \frac{4}{k} = (\frac{14^{2}}{2}-14x_{0})-(\frac{12^{2}}{2}-12x_{0})
$$

Solving the above 2 equation simultaneously, I got:
$k = \frac{1}{4}N/cm$ and **the natural length $x_{0}= 5cm$**

Comment: Thank you so much! This setup matches similarly to the setup of integrals we've studied in class and makes it much easier for me to understand. Thank you!!! :)

Answer (score 3):

You are right

W= $\int_a^b{F(x)}dx$

And F(x)= kx

Substitute the function

W= $\int_a^b{kx}dx$

You get

W= $\bigg[\frac{kx^2}{2}\bigg]_a^b$

Now , spring doesn't have KE in this situation so $\frac{kx^2}{2}$ denotes the potential energy

In situation number 1 :  a= 8-y

b= 12-y

And
W= 5

[where y is the natural length.]

In situation 2 :a= 12-y

b= 14-y

And
W= 4

where y denotes the same.

You can use these two equations to get the value of y :)

Comment: Just saw the latest comment, thank you for sharing Sean